# VS2010 takes long time to show a project properties

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate installed on my super machine (8 Xeon Processors, 12GB Ram, ...). My problem is that VS2010 takes a long time to open any project properties!!

Does any one knows a fix to this problem?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Zion processors? You don't look very Jewish. :-P

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, Sorry I mean Intel Xeon :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution!! You just need to delete the solution `*.suo` files, it seems they got corrupt!!
After I did that everything returned to normal again, even the solution build process is now several times faster!! :D

[image: .suo Files]